# Is it possible to log events of every user in one Event Log?

Tags: powershell, group-policy, event-log, applocker

Right now if AppLocker blocks a program it is only logged in the local EventLog of the user.

Is it possible to set up one Event Log where the events of any user are logged that can be accessed by an admin? So if user1 tries to execute an .exe that is blocked and user2 tries to execute a program that is blocked as well, both show up in one log?

Is there something like that in GPO?

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might look at Nirsoft's free [FullEventLogView](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/full_event_log_view.html), which combines views of *all* Windows Even Logs, from *all* users. into one view, and which allows viewing logs on other machines, or one of the [many alternatives](https://alternativeto.net/software/event-viewer/):

[image: FullEventLogView]

Answer (score 0):

Windows administrators can [remotely connect](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/host-integration-server/core/how-to-select-computers-in-event-viewer1) to the logs of of the Windows PCs in their domain.

If you are just looking for a single event, you could write a script to scan the log for an event and notify you in some way.  You could even create a custom event log in Windows and log it there.

However, if you are in an organization with a decent number of computers, non-Windows machines, looking for many events, have machines on remote networks, etc, you should look into professional log monitors.